# Calculus math question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So the cost per hour of running a cruiser is $\$ \left(\frac {V^2}{40} + 10\right)$, where $V $is the speed in knots. So I’ve answered the first question showing the cost would be $\$\frac DV \left(\frac {V^2}{40} + 10\right)$. And then they asked me to find the most economical speed for running the cruiser, and I have no idea how to get it

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your post pretty heavily, please check to see that no errors were introduced.

Comment: This has now become a "minimize" problem.  Find the value of $V$ so that $\frac DV \left(\frac {V^2}{40} + 10\right)$ is minimum.  A standard problem from a beginning calculus course.

Comment: And how would I find the value of V? I’m self-teaching myself calculus and I am finding this question challenging

Comment: Nvm. I’ve solve the answer

Comment: Does it now occur that you next need to find minimum of $ V/40+10/V?$

Answer (score 3):

The *most economical speed* will be the one at which the cost ($C$) is minimum. So the problem boils down to
\begin{align} 
& \dfrac{dC}{dV} = 0 \\
\implies & \dfrac{d}{dV} \left[ \dfrac{D}{V} \left( \dfrac{V^{2}}{40} + 10\right)\right] = 0 \\
\implies & D \dfrac{d}{dV} \left( \dfrac{V}{40} + \dfrac{10}{V}\right) = 0 \\
\implies & \dfrac{1}{40} - \dfrac{10}{V^{2}} = 0 \tag{assuming $D > 0$} \\
\implies & V = \sqrt{400} = 20 \tag{since $V \geq 0$}
\end{align}

Hence the speed at which the cost will be minimized will be 20 knots.

Here is a plot of cost vs speed for $D = 20$ (you can choose any positive value). It is clear from the plot that cost attains its minimum value at $V = 20$ knots.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let your cost function be $C(V)$, which is dependent on $V$, the velocity of the cruise. 
$$ C(V) = \frac{D}{V}\left( \frac{V^{2}}{40} + 10  \right) $$
with $D$ as a constant.

*The most economical velocity* is the velocity that makes the *smallest cost*.

Since we already have the cost function, we can find this *economical velocity* by using first derivative of $C(V)$. Since $C(V)$ is continuous for $V>0$, $C(V)$ will attain a minima or maxima value at a certain velocity when its first derivative equals 0 :
$$ C(V) = \frac{DV}{40} + \frac{10D}{V}  $$
$$ C'(V) = \frac{D}{40}  - 10DV^{-2} $$
now you may try to solve 
$$ C'(V) = 0 $$
You could get more than 1 velocities, 
choose the one that makes $C(V)$ as minimum as possible. Is this okay?